# what is the usage of context in strategy pattern?

Tags: strategy-pattern

I know how strategy pattern works, but i can't see the usage of context. I think the interface 
strategy is enough. If i use context, user need to know context and concrete strategy, if not use context, user need to know interface strategy and concrete strategy. I think there's no difference between them. So why is context needed?

Comment: The way I see it, is that the context encapsulates the strategies. Code can hold an instance of the context, and in runtime the strategies can be swapped without affecting the context.

Comment: but if i declare an instance of strategy like IStrategy is = new Strategy1(), and if i want to change i can just set is=new Strategy2(). It seems there's no difference?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct, there is no difference, at least execution wise. Although with a context cleaner code can be developed. For example the context enhances open-closed principle. Having a context makes it easier to implement main critical code where external instrumentation can be applied.